# Transfer data between two remote servers. from sql server to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, transfer

I need to periodically (every day) transfer an SQL Server table from a remote SQL server database to a MYSQL database table.

SQL Server database is under local domain. MYSQL database is hosted in external internet hosting provider

How can implement that issue with a c# desktop application? Have I to open/close an internet port using FTP client?

Best Regards

Comment: You have many, many options. The easiest option is to do a data export to a CSV file, then transfer that file to the other machine and import it into the other serve via `LOAD DATA`. This can all be done through `ssh` which you can automate using C#. A harder/slower/more fragile approach would be to `select *` from the local table and then while fetching doing `insert into remote_table` on the remote server. But this has issues whenever your connection breaks and you need to set up a tunnel from the local machine to the remote server to tunnel the database connection through.

Comment: These might of some help :- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server ,  https://hevodata.com/blog/migrate-mysql-database-between-two-servers/